# Quadratic Functional Differentiability

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, quadratic-forms, adjoint-operators

I would like to solve the following:

*Let $T$ be a self-adjoint bounded operator on a Hilbert space $H$. Consider the quadratic functional $\Phi$* defined by:

\begin{equation}
\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}(Tx,x)
\end{equation}

1. *Show that $\Phi$ is differentiable and $\nabla \Phi=T$*.
2. *Show that $\Phi$ is convex if $T$ is strictly positive.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
   2\Phi(x+h)-2\Phi(x)
          & = (T(x+h),x+h)-(Tx,x) \\
          & = (Tx,x)+(Tx,h)+(Th,x)+(Th,h)-(Tx,x) \\
          & = (Tx,h)+(Th,x)+(Th,h) \\
          & = (Tx,h)+(h,Tx)+(Th,h)
\end{align}
$$
I assume you must be working on a real space, and working with an operator $T$ defined on the whole space, which makes it bounded because it is symmetric. If so, then the linear approximation to $\Phi$ is
$$
          \Phi(x+h)=\Phi(x)+(Tx,h)+o(\|h\|)
$$

Comment: Thank you for your anwer and your time. Well it sure must be continuous and symmetric in order to be bounded and self-adjoint. So, above you prove that $\nabla \Phi (x)(h)=(Tx,h)$ am I right? But what about convexity? Why must the "strictly positive" condition hold?

Comment: @Mitscaype : You have a linear term plus a quadratic term $(Th,h) \ge \delta(h,h)$. That's the second order term.